# When I try to save object using hibernate in belogic this exception appear

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Result set already closed 
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.checkResultSet(ResultSet.java:110) 
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.preInvocationHandler(ResultSet.java:65) 
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl.getString(Unknown Source) 
at org.hibernate.type.StringType.get(StringType.java:41) 
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:184) 
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:173) 
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:126) 
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getDatabaseSnapshot(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1061)
```

Comment: You need to add more information, relevant code, config

Answer (score 0):

With whatever the information you have given, it says Result set is closed and you are trying to access the same result set. So try too see where is that you are closing it.

And for more help please provide the sufficient information.